# Cell phone for an 8-year old, pre-programmed numbers only and works in the UK

Tags: mobile-phone

Are there any cell phones that has only programmed speed dial numbers, no texting keypad and works in the UK?

[This article](http://roogirl.com/35-cell-phones-for-kids/) suggests some of them but I don't believe any of them would work in the UK.

Unsurprisingly none of is being sold in the UK either

Edit: Sadly [this article](http://www.gomonews.com/uk-mnos-missing-out-on-emergency-phones-for-kids/) supports my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only available option that I could find was [OwnFone](http://www.smh.com.au/digital-life/mobiles/ownfone-phone-without-texting-camera-or-internet-pitches-to-parents-20140410-zqt2n.html)

[image: OwnFone]

It's a customized phone that is made specially for the customer based on their order. They company intention is to provide our elders with an emergency easy to use phone however, it can be used a for children as well

- Buttons can be images (or names) in case you child is too young to read
- 999/emergency button is available
- No text, no screen
- Choices of 2, 4, 8 or 12 pre-programmed numbers depending on how much you willing to pay
- Designed and works only in the UK

Biggest downside is that the phone is not SIM-free and it seems you cant even replace the SIM or the battery so you are stuck with the plans offered to you by the company.

The cell phone can be bought from [this website](https://ownfone.com/)

**Edit:** It's available for children now from [Mobile phones for children](http://www.ownfone.com/children)